# Basic Node Commands Not Working After Updating NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, npx

I've attempted to update my node version by deleting nodejs file from ProgramFilesx86 folder and using the windows installer to install the latest file. When I go to try and initialize a node project or npx create-react-app it gives me the following:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v13.8.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\agent.js:114:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)     
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v13.8.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)     
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v13.8.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:169:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
Could not determine Node.js install directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be using `nvm` too. You may want to get rid of it.

Comment: *deleting nodejs file from ProgramFilesx86 folder and using the windows installer to install the latest file* in general, this is not how you upgrade anything in windows ... i.e. there usually never a need to delete the old version before installing the new version ... can safely say that about nodejs - with other software, 99.9% the same, but there's always some software that has a stupid installer, though, usually you'd uninstall (not just delete files) then install the updated version

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you run a newer version of `npm` with an older version of `node`. Make sure no old version of `node` is in your path.